# fpdf want to change SetFillColor for an array dependent on if/else statement

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Ok, will try be as clear as possible here. I am trying to produce a pdf document with various fields that display product information. Essentially, the script that produces the pdf will determine whether a change in the product has been initiated, if it has then the pdf will be created.

What I am trying to do now is highlight the field with those changes. To check whether there are changes I am using the following variables (of which there are about thirty)

```
$cone
$ctwo..... etc
```

An example of the array for the product output in the PDF file is:

```
    $leftHeadArray[0]['leftText']  = 'ID';
    $leftHeadArray[0]['rightText'] = $ID;


    $leftHeadArray[1]['leftText']  = 'start';
    $leftHeadArray[1]['rightText'] = date("d/m/Y", $Start);


    $leftHeadArray[2]['leftText']  = 'End';
    $leftHeadArray[2]['rightText'] = date("d/m/Y", $End);
```

The format and cell is then initated below this at:

```
$maxheader = max(array_keys($leftHeadArray), array_keys($midHeadArray), array_keys($rightHeadArray));

    for ($i = 0; $i <= max($maxheader); $i++)
    {
        if (isset($leftHeadArray[$i]))
        {
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 6);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);

            $pdf->Cell(40, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'N', 6);
            if ($ctwentytwo == 0 && $leftHeadArray[1]['rightText'] || $ctwentytwo == 0 && $leftHeadArray[4]['rightText'] ){
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
            }else{
            $pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
            }

        $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['rightText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, '', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
    }
```

**Things I have tried already:**

1. wrapping if else statements around the inidividual cell arrays

   (e.g. $leftHeadArray[0]['leftText']  = 'ID';
           $leftHeadArray[0]['rightText'] = $ID;)

   and trying to over-ride the set fill color within there
2. putting the if else statement within the if isset section

**Things I am struggling with:**

- connecting the $cone to the $leftheadarray
- changing just the one cell when a change is initiated

I hope this is concise!

//------------------------------ RESOLVED

The variable is always assumed as 0 so needed to make the declatation if $cone == 1 and relate back to the left head array as below: hope this helps!

```
if (isset($leftHeadArray[$i]))
        {
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 6);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);

            $pdf->Cell(40, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'N', 6);

            $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(128, 0, 0);


            if (($ctwentytwo == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion Start Date")
            ||  ($cone == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion ID")
            ||  ($ctwo == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion Type"))#|| $ctwentytwo == 0 && $leftHeadArray[1]['rightText']
            {
                $pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
                $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
            }

            $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['rightText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(20, 5, '', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($leftHeadArray[$i]))
        {
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 6);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(128, 0, 0);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);

            $pdf->Cell(40, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'N', 6);

            $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->SetTextColor(128, 0, 0);


            if (($ctwentytwo == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion Start Date")
            ||  ($cone == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion ID")
            ||  ($ctwo == 1) && ($leftHeadArray[$i]['leftText'] == "Promotion Type"))#|| $ctwentytwo == 0 && $leftHeadArray[1]['rightText']
            {
                $pdf->SetFillColor(0, 0, 0);
                $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
            }

            $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $leftHeadArray[$i]['rightText'], $border, 0, 'L', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(20, 5, '', 0, 0, 'L', 0);
        }
```

Comment: This is the answer for future reference